# Leaflet map with tile layer only on top corner

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, leaflet

I'm developing a project with Ionic 5 and Vue.js, and in one of my screens I am using an leaflet map that must cover almost the entire screen.

I am using the [Leaflet library for vue](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/), and my code looks like this:

```js
<template>
  <section class="map-container">
    <l-map
          ref="map"
          :options="mapOptions"
          :bounds="bounds"
          v-on:update:zoom="zoomUpdated"
          @ready="mapReady"
        >
      <l-tile-layer :url="'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'">
      </l-tile-layer>
  </l-map>
  </section>
</template>


<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import { mapState, mapGetters } from "vuex";
import Leaflet from "leaflet";
import store from '../store/index'
import Vue2LeafletGoogleMutant from "vue2-leaflet-googlemutant";
import { LMap, LTileLayer, LPolygon, LImageOverlay } from "vue2-leaflet";

export default {
  name: "MapBackground",
  store,
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState("maps", ["gMapsKey", "bounds", "selected"]),
  },
  methods: {
    zoomUpdated(zoomLevel) {
      if (zoomLevel <= 13) {
        this.$store.commit("maps/selected", -1);
      }
    },
    mapReady() {
      this.$refs.map.mapObject.invalidateSize()
      const { map } = this.$refs;
      map.mapObject.on("click", this.selectTalhao);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      mapOptions: {
        zoomControl: false,
        doubleClickZoom: false,
        tap: false,
        trackResize: false
      },
      mutantOptions: { type: "satellite", redraw: true },
    };
  },
  watch: {
  },
  async created() {
    await this.$store.dispatch("maps/updateBounds", { point: null });
    this.$refs.map.mapObject.invalidateSize()
  }
};
</script>
```

However, when i load the screen for the first time, our reload the tab in the browser, my map looks like this:[Map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H9jS.png)

I've tried using invalidateSize, checked if the height of the div had changed and nothing. Don't know what else can I do to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a symptom of not initializing the map size, and/or a missing `invalidateSize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work for all types of ionic application. the issue is due to loading of leaflet map before the ionic components. so try the below one it should work

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
   let osmMap = L.map('map');
   L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
   }).addTo(osmMap);
   osmMap.invalidateSize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular it should help

```
    import * as L from 'leaflet';   
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
    })
    export class HomePage implements OnInit {
     ngOnInit(){
      let osmMap = L.map('map');
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      }).addTo(osmMap);
    let customMarkerIcon = await icon({
            iconUrl: 'assets/images/test.png',
            iconSize: [50, 50], 
            popupAnchor: [0, -20]
          }); 
  L.marker([11.203,12.300],{icon:customMarkerIcon}).addTo(osmMap);
     const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
          osmMap.invalidateSize();
          osmMap.setView([11.203,12.300],20);
          observer.disconnect();
        });
        observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
          attributes: true,
          attributeFilter: ['class'],
          childList: false,
          characterData: false,
        });
    }
}
```